Migrated from Tomcat 8.0 to Tomcat 10.1
We are currently migrating our system from Elastic Beanstalk Platform(Corretto 8 & Tomcat 8.1) to (Corretto 17 & Tomcat 10.1). I am getting HTTP Status 400 from an HTTP request sent by a host through DNS. I suspected it's a problem in my Tomcat configuration since there were a lot of changes on Tomcat 10.1.
Note:

I have no info on the development phase of this project.
This is from server.xml. Most of the configurations are the same and I only show the connectors.
This request is also sent from a firmware that I can't access the code to so I cant provide any details of the HTTP request only the AccessLogValve
I can provide additional info if needed but this is as much as I can show. Thanks
I have checked the migration guide for tomcat 10.1 but so far i haven't figured out what I need

Connectors in Tomcat 8.0
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" maxThreads="200" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

Connectors in Tomcat 10.1
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"  allowHostHeaderMismatch="true" 
    rejectIllegalHeader="false"/>

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" sslProtocol="TLS" maxConnections="1000" port="443" scheme="https" allowHostHeaderMismatch="true" 
    rejectIllegalHeader="false" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" secure="true" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyAlias="localhost" certificateKeystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" certificateKeystorePassword="changeit" type="RSA"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" address="::1"/>


A sample log when I sent the the request from the AccessLogValve
192.168.1.18 - - [16/Jul/2024:15:14:45 +0800] "-" 400 -

I tried changing the certificate alias since there are two that I can use tomcat and localhost, i tried changing the values of the rejectIllegalHeaders=false and allowHostHeaderMismatch=true since the default config for Tomcat 8 is the opposite in 10. Have I missed other configurations from Tomcat 8?
UPDATE
I tried checking the SSL Handshake process via Wireshark it turns out during the Server Hello step the request fails. Here is the content of the Wireshark log. I also checked the data(Frame, Ethernet, IPv4) on the OK request from TC 8 it seems that most of the data are consistent with the BAD requests. The difference is only that on the TCP it is sent to a different port(OK: 3058, BAD: 3643) and on the Conversation Completeness(OK: Incomplete DATA 15, BAD: Complete WITH_DATA 31).
enter image description here

A 400 probably means the TC is running but does not like your test request payload. If it was a cert issue you would probably not get a https connection. The fact you did not get a 404 is also evidence that TC is ok. You will need to look in the detailed TC logs for the cause of the 400 response. Can you not set the TC up locally to test?

@JohnWilliams thank you for the response, I am testing TC on a local setup. Our local setup is configured to run with a DNS server to reroute the requests from the device to the TC server locally. I have done tests using Postman so far I get OK responses from it by using the host IP from the log 192.168.1.18. It turns out that IP is the remote host name and using it on the host header for postman doesn't replicate the case.

If it works from postman, that’s more reason to check TC logs locally (%TOMCAT_HOME%/logs recently updated files).

Unfortunately, this is the only logs I get [INFO    2024-07-17 16:52:08,723 [main] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version  - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.1.Final
]

There must be other logs somewhere - TC can be messy about location of logs. Try to set the logging level to DEBUG?

Suggesting to inspect catalina.out and post relevant errors+warnings to the question.

notice:  is redirecting to undefined connector on port 8443.

@JohnWilliams Unfortunately TC logs are still unhelpful i tried the RequestDumpFilter valve but still no useful info yet. I am currently trying wireshark to check the SSL handshake process it turns out my request fails at the Server Hello step. Thank you for your input.

@DudiBoy will try to check that too. Also, my AJP connector had the same redirect port on out TC 8 version. This seems to be an SSL config problem based on the Wireshark logs. Thank you still for the input.
